# jquery first-child on a fadeIn fadeOut list doesn't work

Tags: jquery, list, bind, fadein, css-selectors

Chaps,  I got this list that doesn't open the other list.

http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/147/

I want to display the first child and then on click display the other items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/149/

```
$("ul#links li a").unbind().bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(".descriptions").fadeOut();
    //you must get the index of the parent <li> otherwise the index of the <a> is always 0!
    var index = $(this).parent().index();

    $(".descriptions").eq(index).fadeIn();

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

}, function(e) {
    $(".descriptions").stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: thansk dude, on my local version all the divs are on display none...!"!!

Comment: Nicola, do you know why? cos is not working with the latest vesion on jquery 7.1

any Idea why?

Comment: @DD77 they changed the way event are handled in 1.7, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/157/

Answer (score 0):

Hi modified you code http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/150/
Basicall using href of the clicked anchor ,getting descriptions div and toggling it.Please let me know if you are looking for something else.